# Add List Item Using Web Service as Current User

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, sharepoint

I can successfully add a list item to a list with an asp.net web application.  However, the "Created By" field holds the name of the server, rather than the current user visiting the site.

Server A hosts my asp.net web app.  A user visits the site, clicks a button, which adds the item to Server B, which hosts the SharePoint site.  I have no access to Server B, hence the use of the web service.

Here's my current code:

```
webreference.Lists myList = new webreference.Lists();  
//have also tried DefaultNetworkCredentials   
myList.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;    
myList.Url = "http://site/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";    
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();    
XmlElement batch = doc.CreateElement("Batch");   
batch.SetAttribute("OnError", "Continue");   
batch.InnerXml = "<Method ID='1' Cmd='New'>" +   
"<Field Name='Title'>Test</Field>" +    
"</Method>";    
myList.UpdateListItems("{LIST GUID}", batch);
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with things like "Csharp SharePoint". That's what we use tags for on [so].

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in order to pass credentials like this between tiers you'd need to be using Kerberos to delegate. Otherwise DefaultCredentials will be null. This is known as the NTML "double hop" problem. Look at [this post on MSDN Forums where the fellow suggests changing NTAuthenticationProviders](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-MY/asmxandxml/thread/19f97e75-852d-4d5d-b0ca-4e722ab5265f).